# Authorized changes in DB through forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I grant access to change values in database through forms in ASP.NET MVC5 application by creating specific users and passwords to allow them to make changes? My customer does not want to build the solution based on logins. The full content can be visible for anyone (without logging in) but changes to database can be done only when the specific user enters his credentials (username, password) and hit the "Set" button, see pic. I tried some things like setting basic "if else" condition when the username and passwords are the same as in the SQL table but the changes can be done even without entering credentials into fields. 
link to pic:

[image]

My Edit Viewpage:

```
@model Company.Models.SovaGenNastaveni
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage1.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Content/styles/EditForms.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="states" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Current Values</h4>
    </div>

    <table id="FormEdit" class="table table-bordered">

        <tr>
            <th>Item name</th>
            <td>@Model.settingsName</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="alert alert-primary">State</th>
            @if
                (Model.State == 101)
            {
                <td class="alert alert-success"><strong>Active</strong></td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td class="alert alert-danger"><strong>InActive</strong></td>
            }
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Description of settings</th>
            <td>@Model.settingsDesc</td>
        </tr>
    </table>



    <form id="formEdit" action="/SimulationSettings/edit/@Model.ID" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <h4>Change state</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                <label for="Hodnota">Choose a new <strong>Hodnota</strong></label>

                <select class="form-control" id="ChooseState" name="State">
                    <option value="@Model.State">---Choose---</option>
                    <option value="101">Active</option>
                    <option value="102">InActive</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                <label for="Hodnota">Confirm your rights</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="username" value="" />
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="password" />
            </div>
        </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Set</button>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/SimulationSettings/Settings">Cancel</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(long id)
        {
            SiempelLinkedServerEntities db = new SiempelLinkedServerEntities();
            SovaGenNastaveni existingSetting = db.SovaGenNastavenis.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(existingSetting);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        //[Authorize]???
        public ActionResult Edit(SovaGenNastaveni genNastaveni)
        {
            SiempelLinkedServerEntities db = new SiempelLinkedServerEntities();
            SovaGenNastaveni existingSetting = db.SovaGenNastavenis.Where(x => x.ID == genNastaveni.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            existingSetting.State = genNastaveni.State;


            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Settings", "SimulationSettings");
        }
```

Model is designed and generated from SQL Server (EF Designer, DB-First Approach)

In SQL Server I have a table with 3 columns = ID, username, password(this maybe going to be encrypted with hash).
The solution should be deployed only in Intranet of the company. No neccessary security or safety needed.

In short, the edit page should be authorized, when the granted user enter his credentials the changes will be made to DB, if there are no credentials filled should nothing happen.

Even I will be happy if you can suggest or recommend some kind of specific tutorial for this type authorization.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of something i've used

Get Request

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ClientToDB : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SendForValues());
    }

    IEnumerator SendForValues()
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://" + StaticValues.ip + "/empires/ClientToDB.php"))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.downloadHandler.text != "0")
            {
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Sucessfully Sent");

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Post

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class RegisterUser : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField Field;

    public void CreateUser()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("EmpireName", Field.text);

        StartCoroutine(StartRegisterUser());


    }

    IEnumerator StartRegisterUser()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

        form.AddField("name", PlayerPrefs.GetString("EmpireName", ""));
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://" + StaticValues.ip + "/empires/UserCreateAccount.php", form))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

            if (www.downloadHandler.text[0] != '0')
            {
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
                Debug.Log("Sucessfully Sent");
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("EmpireCreated", 1);
                SceneManager.LoadScene(2);

                int id = int.Parse(www.downloadHandler.text.Split('\t')[1]);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("id", id);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

I used php to receive the request so to get information with php you use $_POST["KEY"]
and to send it you use form.AddField("KEY", PlayerPrefs.GetString("EmpireName", ""));